# Replacing list elements by other list elements

Tags: list-manipulation

I am a beginner of *Mathematica* and need some help for the following issue.

I have the following two lists:

```
NamesandIDs = {{"ccc", 05}, {"ggg", 03}, {"zzz", 17}}

data = {{"zzz", 50, 30}, {"zzz", 49, 32}, {"ccc", 49, 21}, {"ccc", 27, 68},
        {"ggg", 72, 38}, {"ggg", 77, 59}}
```

In `NamesandIDs` the first element of each list is a name and the second is ID number corresponding to each name; `data` contains some data for each name. With the two lists, what I wanna do is two things.

- Replacing names in `data` by the corresponding IDs, i.e. I would like to have the following result:

  ```
  data = {{17, 50, 30}, {17, 49, 32}, {05, 49, 21}, {05, 27, 68}, {03, 72, 38}, 
          {03, 77, 59}}
  ```
- Inserting the ID corresponding to each name into the second position of each list in "data," i.e. I would like to have:

  ```
  data = {{"zzz", 17, 50, 30}, {"zzz", 17, 49, 32}, {"ccc", 05, 49, 21}, 
          {"ccc", 05, 27, 68}, {"ggg", 03, 72, 38}, {"ggg", 03, 77, 59}}
  ```

I highly appreciate if someone could let me know how to come up with the two results above. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Probably a duplicate, help me find it :) 1) `data /. Rule @@@ NamesandIDs` 2) `ata /. (# -> Sequence[##] & @@@ NamesandIDs)`

Comment: Ok,I'd say this is a duplicate: [Join lists based on conditions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42483/5478) but your is more clear or useful for future visitors. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Kuba! I highly appreciate it!

Comment: Oh, sorry. I couldn't notice the suggested post with answers. It is perfectly fine if the webmaster(s) remove my question. Many thanks to Kuba, anyway!

Comment: No, it will stay as a good road sign for future visitors :)

Comment: @Kuba, it really deserves to be an answer here as it differs from your answer elsewhere. And the question example might be simplified a bit as it seems to be a typical task.